# Phonenumber masking in React

Tags: reactjs

input-mask in React js project.
My code looks like this.

```
                  <InputMask mask="(999)999-9999" maskChar=" ">
                    {() => (
                      <TextField
                        defaultValue="2223334444"
                        helperText="ex) 2134445555"
                        label="Phone Number"
                        color="secondary"
                        className={classes.textField}
                        inputProps={{
                          onChange: (e) => {
                            if (validateLength(churchPhonenumber, 5, 15)) {
                              setChurchPhonenumberState("success");
                            } else {
                              setChurchPhonenumberState("error");
                            }
                            setChurchPhonenumber(e.target.value);
                          },
                        }}
                      />
                    )}
                  </InputMask>
```

It shows a textfield but I can't type in it!
And also doesn't show default value.

Answer (score 0):

phone-number-input for phone number masking.

```
import 'react-phone-number-input/style.css'
import PhoneInput from 'react-phone-number-input'

function Example() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState()
  return (
    <PhoneInput
      placeholder="Enter phone number"
      value={value}
      onChange={setValue}/>
  )
}
```

Please check the [Source](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-phone-number-input) and [Demo](https://catamphetamine.gitlab.io/react-phone-number-input/)